# How to make a click run two functions in actionscript 3?

Tags: actionscript-3, function, click, call

I was wondering if it was possible to call two different functions from one mouse event, like click. I figured it might just be something like:

```
    button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function1 && function2);
```

Unfortunately that doesn't work. Do i need to call a new function that contains those two?
For example

```
   button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function3);
   function function3(){
       function1();
       function2();
   }
```

The latter seems very inefficient so i assume there is a way to do it like the prior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either do that or register two Click event handlers, or you could write the function inline (inside the addEventListener) such as

```
button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.Click, function(e:Event):void {
      function2();
      function3();
}):
```